# easy_install of cross compiled netifaces 0.8 python module fails because it "could not find suitable distribution"

Tags: python, arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, egg

I'm cross compiling the 'netifaces' Python module for ARM using the Digi Embedded Linux toolchain on an Ubuntu 12.04.4 32-bit host but am having trouble getting my target device to install it correctly.  Ultimately, I'd like to include the netifaces' artifacts in my rootfs, but that comes after this.

Here's my steps for the cross compile:

```
$ wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.8.tar.gz
$ tar xzf netifaces-0.8.tar.gz
$ cd netifaces-0.8
$ PYTHONXCPREFIX=/path/to/digi/sysroot/with/xc-python2.7/added/usr CROSS_COMPILE=arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi- CC="arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-gcc -pthread" LDSHARED="arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-gcc -pthread -shared" LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/digi/sysroot/with/xc-python2.7/added/usr/lib -L/path/to/digi/sysroot/with/xc-python2.7/added/lib" python setup.py build -x bdist_egg --plat-name=linux-arm

options (after parsing config files):
options (after parsing command line):
option dict for 'aliases' command:
  {}
option dict for 'bdist_egg' command:
  {'plat_name': ('command line', 'linux-arm')}
option dict for 'build' command:
  {'cross_compile': ('command line', 1), 'debug': ('command line', 1)}
option dict for 'egg_info' command:
  {'tag_build': ('setup.cfg', ''),
   'tag_date': ('setup.cfg', '0'),
   'tag_svn_revision': ('setup.cfg', '0')}
running build
Distribution.get_command_obj(): creating 'build' command object
  setting options for 'build' command:
    debug = 1 (from command line)
    cross_compile = 1 (from command line)
Setting prefix
running build_ext
Distribution.get_command_obj(): creating 'build_ext' command object
checking for getifaddrs...found. 
checking for getnameinfo...found. 
checking for optional header files...netash/ash.h netatalk/at.h netax25/ax25.h neteconet/ec.h netipx/ipx.h netpacket/packet.h linux/irda.h linux/atm.h linux/llc.h linux/tipc.h linux/dn.h. 
checking whether struct sockaddr has a length field...no. 
checking which sockaddr_xxx structs are defined...at ax25 in in6 ipx un ash ec ll atmpvc atmsvc dn irda llc. 
building 'netifaces' extension
arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -g -DNETIFACES_VERSION=0.8 -DHAVE_GETIFADDRS=1 -DHAVE_GETNAMEINFO=1 -DHAVE_NETASH_ASH_H=1 -DHAVE_NETATALK_AT_H=1 -DHAVE_NETAX25_AX25_H=1 -DHAVE_NETECONET_EC_H=1 -DHAVE_NETIPX_IPX_H=1 -DHAVE_NETPACKET_PACKET_H=1 -DHAVE_LINUX_IRDA_H=1 -DHAVE_LINUX_ATM_H=1 -DHAVE_LINUX_LLC_H=1 -DHAVE_LINUX_TIPC_H=1 -DHAVE_LINUX_DN_H=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_AT=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_AX25=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_IN=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_IN6=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_IPX=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_UN=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_ASH=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_EC=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_LL=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_ATMPVC=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_ATMSVC=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_DN=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_IRDA=1 -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_LLC=1 -I/path/to/digi/sysroot/with/xc-python2.7/added/usr/include/python2.7 -c netifaces.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/netifaces.o
creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.7
arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-gcc -pthread -shared -L/path/to/digi/sysroot/with/xc-python2.7/added/usr/lib -L/path/to/digi/sysroot/with/xc-python2.7/added/lib -g build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/netifaces.o -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/netifaces.so
running bdist_egg
Distribution.get_command_obj(): creating 'bdist_egg' command object
  setting options for 'bdist_egg' command:
    plat_name = linux-arm (from command line)
Distribution.get_command_obj(): creating 'egg_info' command object
  setting options for 'egg_info' command:
    tag_build =  (from setup.cfg)
    tag_date = 0 (from setup.cfg)
    tag_svn_revision = 0 (from setup.cfg)
Distribution.get_command_obj(): creating 'bdist' command object
running egg_info
writing netifaces.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to netifaces.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to netifaces.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'netifaces.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
include_pattern: applying regex r'^netifaces\.egg\-info/.*[^/]*\Z(?ms)'
 adding netifaces.egg-info/PKG-INFO
 adding netifaces.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
 adding netifaces.egg-info/top_level.txt
 adding netifaces.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
exclude_pattern: applying regex r'^build/.*'
exclude_pattern: applying regex r'^netifaces\-0\.8/.*'
exclude_pattern: applying regex r'\/(RCS|CVS|\.svn)\/'
writing manifest file 'netifaces.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-i686/egg
Distribution.get_command_obj(): creating 'install' command object
pre-finalize_{unix,other}:
  prefix: None
  exec_prefix: None
  home: None
  user: 0
  install_base: None
  install_platbase: None
  root: None
  install_purelib: None
  install_platlib: None
  install_lib: None
  install_headers: None
  install_scripts: None
  install_data: None
  compile: None
  compile: True
  optimize: None
  force: None
  skip_build: 0
  record: None
  install_layout: None
  old_and_unmanageable: None
  single_version_externally_managed: None
post-finalize_{unix,other}():
  prefix: /usr
  exec_prefix: /usr
  home: None
  user: 0
  install_base: /usr
  install_platbase: /usr
  root: None
  install_purelib: $base/local/lib/python$py_version_short/dist-packages
  install_platlib: $platbase/local/lib/python$py_version_short/dist-packages
  install_lib: None
  install_headers: $base/local/include/python$py_version_short/$dist_name
  install_scripts: $base/local/bin
  install_data: $base/local
  compile: None
  compile: True
  optimize: None
  force: None
  skip_build: 0
  record: None
  install_layout: None
  old_and_unmanageable: None
  single_version_externally_managed: None
post-expand_basedirs():
  prefix: /usr
  exec_prefix: /usr
  home: None
  user: 0
  install_base: /usr
  install_platbase: /usr
  root: None
  install_purelib: $base/local/lib/python$py_version_short/dist-packages
  install_platlib: $platbase/local/lib/python$py_version_short/dist-packages
  install_lib: None
  install_headers: $base/local/include/python$py_version_short/$dist_name
  install_scripts: $base/local/bin
  install_data: $base/local
  compile: None
  compile: True
  optimize: None
  force: None
  skip_build: 0
  record: None
  install_layout: None
  old_and_unmanageable: None
  single_version_externally_managed: None
config vars:
{'base': '/usr',
 'dist_fullname': 'netifaces-0.8',
 'dist_name': 'netifaces',
 'dist_version': '0.8',
 'exec_prefix': '/path/to/digi/sysroot/with/xc-python2.7/added/usr',
 'platbase': '/usr',
 'prefix': '/path/to/digi/sysroot/with/xc-python2.7/added/usr',
 'py_version': '2.7.3',
 'py_version_nodot': '27',
 'py_version_short': '2.7',
 'sys_exec_prefix': '/path/to/digi/sysroot/with/xc-python2.7/added/usr',
 'sys_prefix': '/path/to/digi/sysroot/with/xc-python2.7/added/usr',
 'userbase': '/home/myuser/.local',
 'usersite': '/home/myuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'}
post-expand_dirs():
  prefix: /usr
  exec_prefix: /usr
  home: None
  user: 0
  install_base: /usr
  install_platbase: /usr
  root: None
  install_purelib: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  install_platlib: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  install_lib: None
  install_headers: /usr/local/include/python2.7/netifaces
  install_scripts: /usr/local/bin
  install_data: /usr/local
  compile: None
  compile: True
  optimize: None
  force: None
  skip_build: 0
  record: None
  install_layout: None
  old_and_unmanageable: None
  single_version_externally_managed: None
after prepending root:
  prefix: /usr
  exec_prefix: /usr
  home: None
  user: 0
  install_base: /usr
  install_platbase: /usr
  root: None
  install_purelib: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  install_platlib: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  install_lib: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
  install_headers: /usr/local/include/python2.7/netifaces
  install_scripts: /usr/local/bin
  install_data: /usr/local
  compile: None
  compile: True
  optimize: None
  force: None
  skip_build: 0
  record: None
  install_layout: None
  old_and_unmanageable: None
  single_version_externally_managed: None
Distribution.get_command_obj(): creating 'install_lib' command object
running install_lib
creating build/bdist.linux-i686
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg
copying build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/netifaces.so -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg
creating stub loader for netifaces.so
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/netifaces.py to netifaces.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying netifaces.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying netifaces.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying netifaces.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying netifaces.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
writing build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO/native_libs.txt
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating dist
creating 'dist/netifaces-0.8-py2.7-linux-arm.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-i686/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-i686/egg' (and everything under it)
```

(The above snippet has paths change to protect the innocent.)

I know the compilation was for ARM (and not host) as the following appears correct:

```
$ file build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/netifaces.so

build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/netifaces.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

This gives me a dist/netifaces-0.8-py2.7-linux-arm.egg artifact.  I copy this artifact over to my target device and run easy_install (no pip available).  I don't want the target device to go to the internet to grab things from pypi, as this device needs to have a controlled config and there are no compilers resident on the device to compile pypi packages anyway. It errors like so:

```
# uname -a

Linux devicename 2.6.35.14 #1 Thu May 15 10:25:00 CDT 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux

# python --version

Python 2.7.3

# easy_install -v -H None -f ./ netifaces-0.8-py2.7-linux-arm.egg

Processing netifaces-0.8-py2.7-linux-arm.egg
Copying netifaces-0.8-py2.7-linux-arm.egg to /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Adding netifaces 0.8 to easy-install.pth file
Saving /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth

Installed /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/netifaces-0.8-py2.7-linux-arm.egg
Processing dependencies for netifaces==0.8
Searching for netifaces==0.8

Note: Bypassing https://pypi.python.org/simple/netifaces/ (disallowed host; see http://bit.ly/1dg9ijs for details).

Couldn't find index page for 'netifaces' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)

Note: Bypassing https://pypi.python.org/simple/ (disallowed host; see http://bit.ly/1dg9ijs for details).

No local packages or download links found for netifaces==0.8
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('netifaces==0.8')
```

I've also tried the above command with just 'netifaces' as the package argument, to no avail.

I do get a different result when I remove the '-H None' argument (allowing it to go visit pypi), but it obviously errors because there is no compiler available.  I don't want to use this approach anyway, but I include it here for completeness.

```
# easy_install -v -f ./ netifaces-0.8-py2.7-linux-arm.egg 

Processing netifaces-0.8-py2.7-linux-arm.egg
Copying netifaces-0.8-py2.7-linux-arm.egg to /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Adding netifaces 0.8 to easy-install.pth file
Saving /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth

Installed /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/netifaces-0.8-py2.7-linux-arm.egg
Processing dependencies for netifaces==0.8
Searching for netifaces==0.8
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/netifaces/
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.1-py2.6-win32.egg#md5=c8c5f7e4a403dd416b435ad8eddefed1
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.1.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=bf229517b6b3d40ad0991fc6b504043d
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.2-py2.6-win32.egg#md5=07fb22d2408bf2969c18cfa1711bd5d6
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.2.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=e55e5fd188e4e6fda21942b665a2fca3
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.3-py2.6-win32.egg#md5=1b0c3b5a76bd543d45ec4d6fa50f29f4
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.3.win32-py2.6.exe#md5=da9e984985970d7ced4dd69314ac0e14
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg#md5=4bf3f4a83c84d7c7fab7f50958948c2f
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg#md5=c1f80786a62a088a0d882a7291fc0003
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.0-py2.7-win32.egg#md5=5dc7c3e416371423ac966fcb152272ff
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.1-py2.7-win32.egg#md5=0295b17dc388d2cb5ac73a50dbd2e6e4
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.1.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=b1584b3a9db0c763c94511f4e508f4fe
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.2-py2.7-win32.egg#md5=cd06faf5faccc13f71bad4bde03de3c1
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.2.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=9b2e1fb6a8c4a4325e33884fafeb7882
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.3-py2.7-win32.egg#md5=aacaa28c603070e4347630d76e5a5df9
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.3.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=78647c9bade6880b99c7462a46648bc5
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.1-py3.3-win32.egg#md5=f10939775f4ec4806e0d43582f090925
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.1.win32-py3.3.exe#md5=11b6f9f84eb42f53d574dfd9f1326164
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.2-py3.3-win32.egg#md5=1a0b71b320246eaed195bd61c4dce4e1
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.2.win32-py3.3.exe#md5=d2738c8bf7401f860a813a9e20ab168d
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.3-py3.3-win32.egg#md5=95a1732bd403d7afb1ab02ca230cc40c
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.3.win32-py3.3.exe#md5=68f654fe15512642a708e40f5dc0b5b0
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.0-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg#md5=a0653891e193ab87e33f6688c229e2e8
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.0-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg#md5=12fe125c18eb1103efa1b5b24d8eafb6
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.0-py3.4-win32.egg#md5=1c96ff8e56893e2a87292481c9a1e385
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.1-py3.4-win32.egg#md5=7ccc760d873a547d967876e180094f31
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.1.win32-py3.4.exe#md5=c191ecd57dd0d5d479a7d5b3607bd889
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.2-py3.4-win32.egg#md5=d2aa751f68d96c3f81a1065527a7bccf
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.2.win32-py3.4.exe#md5=911b9bd3621b6beee6c7547051ecdf6f
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.3-py3.4-win32.egg#md5=dcc30c3564308115b86046bb45659ccb
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.3.win32-py3.4.exe#md5=d62ab19a1cc07bfafcfb1a9f7660231b
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.0.tar.gz#md5=bbe634bd373b3f05df5f4ac23bc92a8f
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.1.tar.gz#md5=4f92ca84e8cb1ce547998e7212ac313d
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.2.tar.gz#md5=acb11ba95d892519825e170d814ee296
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.3.tar.gz#md5=b96913473e1dcc3c4a7c43bc15d10e26
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.4.tar.gz#md5=36da76e2cfadd24cc7510c2c0012eb1e
Found link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.8.tar.gz#md5=e57e5983f4c286fac5f8068fbfc5c873
Found link: http://alastairs-place.net/projects/netifaces/netifaces-0.8.tar.gz#md5=e57e5983f4c286fac5f8068fbfc5c873
Best match: netifaces 0.8
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.8.tar.gz#md5=e57e5983f4c286fac5f8068fbfc5c873
Validating md5 checksum for /tmp/easy_install-k1bwIN/netifaces-0.8.tar.gz
Processing netifaces-0.8.tar.gz
Unpacking netifaces-0.8 to /tmp/easy_install-k1bwIN/netifaces-0.8
Unpacking netifaces-0.8/PKG-INFO to /tmp/easy_install-k1bwIN/netifaces-0.8/PKG-INFO
Unpacking netifaces-0.8/README to /tmp/easy_install-k1bwIN/netifaces-0.8/README
Unpacking netifaces-0.8/netifaces.c to /tmp/easy_install-k1bwIN/netifaces-0.8/netifaces.c
Unpacking netifaces-0.8/netifaces.egg-info to /tmp/easy_install-k1bwIN/netifaces-0.8/netifaces.egg-info
Unpacking netifaces-0.8/netifaces.egg-info/PKG-INFO to /tmp/easy_install-k1bwIN/netifaces-0.8/netifaces.egg-info/PKG-INFO
Unpacking netifaces-0.8/netifaces.egg-info/SOURCES.txt to /tmp/easy_install-k1bwIN/netifaces-0.8/netifaces.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
Unpacking netifaces-0.8/netifaces.egg-info/dependency_links.txt to /tmp/easy_install-k1bwIN/netifaces-0.8/netifaces.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
Unpacking netifaces-0.8/netifaces.egg-info/top_level.txt to /tmp/easy_install-k1bwIN/netifaces-0.8/netifaces.egg-info/top_level.txt
Unpacking netifaces-0.8/setup.cfg to /tmp/easy_install-k1bwIN/netifaces-0.8/setup.cfg
Unpacking netifaces-0.8/setup.py to /tmp/easy_install-k1bwIN/netifaces-0.8/setup.py
Reading configuration from /tmp/easy_install-k1bwIN/netifaces-0.8/setup.cfg
Adding new section [easy_install] to /tmp/easy_install-k1bwIN/netifaces-0.8/setup.cfg
Setting easy_install.find-links to '.' in /tmp/easy_install-k1bwIN/netifaces-0.8/setup.cfg
Writing /tmp/easy_install-k1bwIN/netifaces-0.8/setup.cfg
Running netifaces-0.8/setup.py bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-k1bwIN/netifaces-0.8/egg-dist-tmp-1l9yta
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing netifaces.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to netifaces.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to netifaces.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'netifaces.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'netifaces.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg
running install_lib
running build_ext
checking for getifaddrs...not found. 
checking for getnameinfo...not found. 
checking for socket IOCTLs...not found. 
checking for optional header files...none found. 
checking whether struct sockaddr has a length field...no. 
checking which sockaddr_xxx structs are defined...none! 
building 'netifaces' extension
arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DNETIFACES_VERSION=0.8 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c netifaces.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/netifaces.o
unable to execute arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-gcc: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

So why does easy_install not find a suitable distribution when I attempt to install my locally-compiled, locally-resident bdist egg?  As far as I can tell, the egg is formatted properly and its artifacts are for ARM.  I didn't go patching files or anything in the source tar.gz.  What am I doing wrong?